# Installing pylinkgrammar throws error " error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl .exe' failed with exit status 2"

Tags: visual-studio, python-3.x, link-grammar

i am trying to install pylinkgrammar in python 3.6 on my windowns 7 system, after installing "Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0" and "Visual C++ Build tools", installing "pip install pylinkgrammar" throws error saying "" error: command 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2"", any idea how to fix this?, thanks

Answer (score 1):

"pylinkgrammar" is not supported anymore.
The link-grammar release now contains its own Python support (for both Python 2 and 3).
You can download the latest link-grammar release from https://www.abisource.com/projects/link-grammar/ .
The Windows compilation and run instructions are in `msvc14/README.md`.

In order to easily compile it, you need some experience in compiling C programs under Visual-Studio, and in using libraries.

Another option you may consider is to install it under Linux (a recent link-grammar version is available for installation for all the major Linux distributions). In such a case it is said to work "out of the box" - no compilation is needed. Even then, you may like to download the sources, in order to look at the directory `bindings/python-examples`.